# Why my computer of each session will be running a CMD program?

Tags: batch

Will pop up a black to run the program frame, the closure not appear

Comment: >>>>>>>> what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i suppose you are running on windows. 
Second: your question is too generic with many possible answers. I try to explain some.

Then with this assumption:
there are several causes that could answer your question.

1. If your computer is your workstation at office, probably your company decided to run some startup script when you login (cleanu folder/history/etc)
2. You have installed some programs that needs to launch a script every login.
3. Maybe you have a trojan horse or something similar, if this is the case, then probably you can try to run software like "SpyBot search and destroy" and also an antivirus to check if you have some malware installed.

Comment: why?why?why?why?why?why?